# Disable compare button on product page

Tags: magento2, product, compare

I have followed other tags and I have the following code in my `default.xml` in my child theme. All the other compare functions are disabled with this code except for on the product page. **Why won't this disable compare on the product page?**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="related.product.addto.compare" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="upsell.product.addto.compare" remove="true"/>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: I would advise you to enable template block hints in Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Debug. Find the block name which loads the compare functionality you wish to disable and then add it to your default.xml the same way you removed these other compare blocks.

Comment: Is not disabled products listing page or product details(view) page?

Comment: when I turn on hints the path is app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addto.phtml (but I can't find anything that refers to compare in that file) and the block shows: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor.

Answer (score 4):

> you need Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml with the following code to remove the link on the product page:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
     </body>
</page>
```

> Not tested yet !

Comment: This cannot be because catalog.compare.sidebar is not in catalog_product_view.xml .

Comment: As you can see in my code snippet.... I already added these to the default.xml

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml file

```
 <referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true"/>
```

clear cache and check

Answer (score 0):

Add this to remove from product page in default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addto" remove="true"/>
```